# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Ethernet not working

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my desktop PC and i can not get the Ethernet to work.

That's my network configuration and some outputs:

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:55:7f:af  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:25ff:fe55:7faf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4663 (4.6 KB)  TX bytes:12227 (12.2 KB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11454 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:11454 (11.4 KB)

$ sudo lshw -c network

*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:1c:25:55:7f:af
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:fdffc000-fdffc07f ioport:fe00(size=128)

$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

$ sudo gedit /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

(I have only Ethernet, it's a desktop PC)

Any advice to let it working?

Comment: .. and sorry for my english and some code insert errors, i'm italian and new on this site ;D

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest for troubleshooting:

1. Is Ubuntu able to load the right driver?
2. Make sure that the cable is connected if it is a wired connection.
3. Verify the configuration of network interface
4. Verify the configuration of DHCP (both client and server)

From the ifconfig output, it seems that Ubuntu are able to install the correct driver and activate the network interface. So, number 1 is checked.

For number 2, please make sure that the cable is good. Or if it is a wireless connection, and configured with some security, there are extra steps required.

For number 3, there seems to be something missing in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. My file has the following line that relates to eth0

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

If that still doesn't work, for step number 4, the file to investigate is `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Read the man pages for dhcpcd.conf, or post the content here for evaluation

And finally, do make sure that there are DHCP server running in your network